# Location of compiled Android AudioManager.java

Tags: java, android, file, compilation, android-audiomanager

I have modified the android system source file audiomanager.java for my own purposes and compiled the whole ROM. However, i dont want to flash the whole ROM. Which file is audiomanager.java compiled to?

Its location in the source is /frameworks/base/media/java/android/media/audiomanager.java

Thanks!

Comment: This could be a question for the xda forum. http://forum.xda-developers.com/filter.php?cat=Android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's most likely in frameworks.jar